# Mixed Data Type in Excel, IMEX Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb, xls

I am trying to export xls into datatable. Below is my connection string.

```
string path = //xls source path
OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties='Excel8.0;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;HDR=No;ImportMixedTypes=Text'");
```

I set `IMEX=1` and all the other extended properties as I have to deal with mixed datatypes.

Even though I set the connection like that yet I still produced error.

There are **no error messages**, but the inconsistent rows (who don't follow the majority datatype are **set to null instead**).

Can someone tell me what did I miss? Btw, I am using the `OleDbDataAdapter` & `Fill(DataSet)` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that `TypeGuessRows=0;` and `ImportMixedTypes=Text;` are working from connection string and should not be modified in registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\[Wow6432Node\]Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel`)? AFAIK this settings are read from registry. `ImportMixedTypes=Text` is usually by default, but `TypeGuessRows=8`, and should be set to `0` as in your connection string.

Comment: Great Answer... Thx... Any idea how such thing happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "such thing" ?

Comment: I mean why even tough I set the `TypeGuessRows=0` in the connection string explicitly, I still have to manually edit the registry?

Comment: That's because it have no meaning there, so it's just ignored. The meaningful properties are `Excel8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=No;`. `TypeGuessRows` and `ImportMixedTypes` always take their values from registry. Thus, this behaviour is by design.

Comment: After these code is compiled (built) will the users still need to modify the registry value?

Comment: On each different machine - yes. This value is read by Jet Engine at runtime and have nothing to do with program compilation. You can save, change and then restore that value in registry from your program however (if there is enough permissions).