# What is a better alternative to Excel for loading data to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a huge amount of trouble loading spreadsheets into a SQL Server database.

Currently, I'm using an SSIS package to load the data and I have had to make lots of adjustments to get the data to load:

- All numbers must be formatted as text (otherwise they don't load properly).
- Sometimes numbers must be preceded with single quote (') to get them to load.
- If a column has a mix of number cells and text cells, the text cells must come first in the file (otherwise only numbers load and text comes in as NULL).
- OMG, don't even bother trying to load numeric codes with leading zeros.
- If a user changes a column name the file will not load.
- If a user changes a tab name the file won't load.
- If a user adds a new column (even at the end of a sheet) the file won't load.
- Extra sheets in the file is not a problem, thankfully!
- Dates seem sensitive whether or not they will load properly.
- Connection strings to the Excel file must include "IMEX=1" or things are worse.
- Scheduled SSIS jobs must be run as 32-bit even on 64-bit system.

I've been loading the data (usually 200,000-500,000 rows per file) into a table with all fields defined as `nvarchar`. Then, when loaded I transfer that data in the next step of the SSIS package to the working table with typed data fields.

All of the requirements that I must put on the user for how to format the Excel file is really a pain.  We usually have to send the file back multiple times until all the formatting issues are correct before the file will load.  I'd like to eliminate this thrash.

I know I'm not the only one that is facing this type of problem.  So, I must ask...

What is a better alternative to Excel for loading data into a SQL Server database?

Or, am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be using something other than SSIS to load Excel spreadsheets?

Comment: are you converting to a new system, or (as it sounds) are you consistently uploading?  We do our upload from csv or excel.  We have a page that allows the user to select the csv or xml (excel will be later...maybe) and it imports and scrubs the data

Comment: I am constantly uploading spreadsheets to various systems here at work. This is a normal work flow, not an upgrade scenario.  We have a similar system for the users to use. I get involved when they can't figure out why the file is rejected by the system.

Comment: any consistency in the reject reasons?  How much control do you have over the creation of the file to load?  Maybe it is easier to focus on making the original file correct rather than using a different import method (if it works most of the time)

Comment: The users download a template file then populate it with their data to feed the system.  They usually copy-and-paste from other sources or type in their data.

Comment: Your third point about mixed datatypes surely doesn't matter if you're including `IMEX=1` - that forces all columns to be interpretted as text anyway (instead of the usual Excel guessing the type from the first 8 rows, and returning NULL for anything that doesn't conform to that choice).

Comment: Bridge, I've noticed that it works better (it looks deeper into the file) but it doesn't *force* loading as text.  It will still fail if the column is mixed data types.

Comment: @BoltBait I thought it was the other way around - `Imex=1` says treat everything as text, but there's a registry entry which governs how deep to look to guess otherwise. **Edit**: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918279/mixed-data-type-in-excel-imex-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

You can try OpenRowSet:

```
SELECT *
INTO SomeTable
From OpenRowSet('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=\\servername\c$\filename.xls;HDR=YES;IMEX=1', [Sheet2$])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a SQL answer, but an easy one:

You could require the users to copy and paste data to an excel spreadsheet where everything but the data fields to be included are locked. This will prevent many of the pain points described.